# Excel delete entire row where is first cell empty

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx

How do I delete an entire row, when the first cell is empty?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort on `column A` that will put all the blank lines together.
Then you can select all the blank lines in one go and delete them

OR

You select your table, and click filter, then filter on the column and show only `blanks` then select those rows individually (not drag select) and delete them.
[image: See image here]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this like below. You haven't shown what you've tried.

```
Sub DelFirstColBlanks()
On Error Resume Next
Range("A1:A" & Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlUp
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub macro1()

    'Start from cell A1
    Range("A1").Select

    'Keep checking until you reach row let's say 90
    Do While ActiveCell.Row < 90


        'if the current cell is empty
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then

            'delete the enitre row
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp

        Else

            'keep going down
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If


    Loop
End Sub
```